# How to filter a fast fading signal using window method?

Tags: filter, window-functions, hamming-window

Fast fading signal generated: `mean=0, sigma=0.0189`

Using sigma generated white Gaussian noise and Sigma Gaussian =sigma of fast fading. Took auto correlation up to certain threshold and observed beta (std (A.C)) value of both signals is similar up to threshold.

Now I want to filter Gaussian noise using window method by using input beta but I am confused how to use beta in window (any relation formula?) as I want to see overlapping of Gaussian noise and window in order to see the signal is within the window.

Any suggestions?